# No puedo rescatar los valores de un arreglo en mi datatable

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, datatables

Estoy tratando de crear unos botones para aprobar diferentes documentos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando imprimo un valor del arreglo de datos consultado, repite lo mismo en cada uno de ellos, es decir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es cómo si el for que estoy utilizando utilizara la misma ID para todos los botones y no incrementara

Aquí el código de la obtención del arreglo de datos

```
public function getDocumentosPendientes()
        {
                $btnAprobar = '';
                $btnInfo = '';
                //Custom buttoms
                $arrData = $this->model->selectDocumentosPendientes();
                for ($i=0; $i < count($arrData); $i++) {    
                        $btnAprobar = '
                        <form action="AprobarDocumento" method="post">
                        <input name="intIdDocumentoAprobar" type=hidden value='.$arrData[$i]['id_documento'].'>
                        <input name="moduloDocumento" type=hidden value='.$arrData[$i]['modulo'].'>
                          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Aprobar documento</h5>
                                  <a type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true" title="Cerrar">x</span>
                                  </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                  ¿Está seguro(a) de aprobar el documento <b>'.$arrData[$i]['id_documento'].'?</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aprobar</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" title="Aprobación rápida">
                        <i class="far fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                        ';
                        $btnInfo = '
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2" title="Revisar documento">
                            <i class="far fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" > </i>
                            </button>
                        ';          
                    $arrData[$i]['options'] = '<div class="text-center">'.$btnAprobar.$btnInfo.'
                    </div>';
                }
                echo json_encode($arrData,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            
            die();
        }
```

Aquí el código de la datatable

```
var tableDocumentosPendientes;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    tableDocumentosPendientes = $('#tableDocumentosPendientes').dataTable({
        "aProcessing": true,
        "aServerSide": true,
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        "ajax": {
            "url": " " + base_url + "DocumentosPendientes/getDocumentosPendientes",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id_documento" },
            { "data": "nombreFactura" },
            { "data": "razon" },
            { "data": "fecha_vencimiento" },
            {"data": "intValorTotal"},
            {"data": "observaciones"},
            { "data": "options" }
        ],
        'dom': 'fitpr',
        "bDestroy": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "order": [[0, "asc"]]
    });
});

$('#tableDocumentosPendientes').DataTable();
```

Modelo

```
public function selectDocumentosPendientes()
        {
            $whereAdmin = "";
            if($_SESSION['idUser'] != 1 ){
                $whereAdmin = " and fk_usuario_actual =  '".$_SESSION['idUser']."' ";
            }
            $sql = "SELECT id_documento,ruta, nombreFactura,fecha_vencimiento, intValorTotal,observaciones,modulo,egreso,inicio_flujo,estado,usuario_inicial,fk_usuario_actual, ultimo_movimiento, id_proveedor,nit,razon FROM documento d LEFT JOIN proveedores p ON p.id_proveedor = d.fk_proveedor WHERE estado = 'Pendiente de aprobación'".$whereAdmin;
            $request = $this->select_all($sql);
            return $request;
        }
```

Cuando cambio la paginación de la datatable (Por ejemplo, cuando dejo solo una fila por página) el botón si toma el ID del documento a modificar, pero cuando dejo una longitud de página más elevada, los botones toman el ID del primer elemento de la lista de la datatable, me parece que está imprimiendo el mismo botón sin aumentar el contador en cada registro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diría que el fallo está en cuando llamas al modal, pues siempre llamas al mismo id.

Prueba realizando estos cambios:

1. Donde pone esto:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal'.$i.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

2. Y donde pones esto:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" title="Aprobación rápida">
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal'.$i.'" title="Aprobación rápida">
```

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: Excelente, me sirvió a la perfección!

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro! Si esta respuesta cumplimenta tu pregunta recuerda aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente eternamente, gracias. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo.